# rmarkdown error: No issues when launching app from Rstudio, error when accessing through web broswer

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am developing an app on a linux R server that renders a report using rmarkdown.

1) When I launch the app from Rstudio, the report renders and downloads with no issues.
2) When I access the app through a web browser, I get an error: "error in running command".

Note: The exact same files are used for 1 and 2.  To be specific, the files used for 1 and 2 not copies of the same files at different paths, the files used are at the exact same path.

The log reports the error as follows:

> sh: /opt/shiny-server/ext/pandoc/pandoc: No such file or directory
>
> Error in system(paste(shQuote(pandoc_path), "--version"), intern =
>   TRUE) :
>
> error in running command

The code used to create render the report is based on Rstudio's knitr example:

```
output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'scorecard.docx'
    ,

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('/appl/shiny/ali/helpers/scorecard.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'scorecard.Rmd')

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('scorecard.Rmd', word_document())

      file.rename(out, file)
    }
```

I am running R version 3.1.2, Rstudio Version 0.99.442, rmarkdown 0.7, knitr_1.10.5, shiny_0.12.1

Comment: any news on this, I have the same issue with the demo page